# The new API is still under heavy development but you can try it now via Maven Central snapshots

Tags: maven, snapshot

I do not know about 'Mavean Central snapshots', so can anyone explain the sentence below for me, thanks so much!

**The new API is still under heavy development but you can try it now via Maven Central snapshots.**

Answer (score 0):

le an,

Maven Central is a repository for sharing jars, analogous to the way GitHub is a repository for sharing source code.

Saying a jar is under Maven Central "snapshots" means you can get a copy of the jar but it hasn't been tested, might be broken, and might be changed sometime soon.

This is like saying code has been committed to GitHub "development trunk," it's a way of saying "use it at your own risk."

Hope that helps.

Comment: tks! and when I search MavenCentral, the results have 4 items to download. What different among 'pom', 'aar', 'javadoc.jar', 'sources.jar'? And how to use them? Hi!

Comment: le an,
That is a separate question which should go on a separate thread. If I've answered your *original question* to a satisfactory level, please mark my answer as accepted.